# Angular: Child component SVG in Parent Component SVG

Tags: javascript, angular

Parent Component Template:

```
<svg #svg width="1000" height="600">
    <app-child-component></app-child-component>
</svg>
```

Child Component Template:

```
<svg:image *ngFor="let img of imgs"></svg:image>
<svg:path></svg:path>
```

The problem is the SVG is not rendering. Inspecting element, I can see the child component SVG:

```
<app-parent-component>
    <svg #svg width="1000" height="600">
        <app-child-component>
            <image></image>
            <path></path>
        </app-child-component>
    </svg>
</app-parent-component>
```

I expected to see the SVG image and path elements. However, the result is a blank SVG element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as selector of your child `selector: '[app-child-component]'` (see the the `[` `]`. This makes that you can apply as directive and not create extra tag

```
<svg #svg width="1000" height="600" app-child-component>
</svg>

//or

<svg #svg width="1000" height="600" >
   <g app-child-component></g>
</svg>
```

NOTE: your app-child-component like

```
<svg:image *ngFor="let img of imgs" [attr.href]="img"></svg:image>
<svg:path [attr.d]="path"></svg:path>
```

where you declare, e.g.

```
  imgs=[0,1,2].map(x=>"https://picsum.photos/200/300?random="+x)
  path="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"
```